# importing PebbleKit in Xcode 6 for use in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, pebble-sdk

I'm trying to develop a Pebble companion app in Xcode 6 using swift.

I've followed the instructions so far as could be followed from the [pebble development site](http://developer.getpebble.com/2/mobile-app-guide/ios-guide.html)

Pod seems to install and link PebbleKit without any errors, but when I type the "import PebbleKit" directive in a swift file, it says module not found.

Not being an expert in Objective-C, (nor swift, for that matter) I'm at a loss as to why it isn't working.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the following solution.
1. I added the PebbleKit manually (all steps for this are described in the link provided by the question)
2. I made a Bridging Header file in the Swift project (check [Bridging Headers](http://devmonologue.com/ios/swift/using-objective-c-swift/))
3. In the created Bridging Header file, I wrote: #import

No need of adding 'import PebbleKit' into any Swift file! After I could use all classes from the PebbleKit framework without any problems.